# Parsing csv strings into webpages

Tags: csv

I'm a geneticist trying to automate a very laborious search result from my data. I understand that this question may have been asked before, please bear with me as i'm not entirely sure what keywords i should use. Thanks in advance!

What i want to achieve:

Search a specific string of numbers in a website from my list of data (csv file), then select top option. Once in the page, search for specific keyword(s)and return results into csv file.

Rinse repeat for remaining numbers.

That's it. It took me 1 day to do a couple of hundred entries. It takes up too much manpower when i really hope to use my time better than this.

Comment: I assume you're planning to do this in a programming language. Which one?

Comment: This is not very clear.  Can you be more specific, running through an exact example? Start with the line in your csv file, then explain what URL to search (is it the same web URL each time or does the web site URL depend on the csv data?), and what needs to be done while on that web page.

Comment: Also:  It is usually more efficient to obtain an entire dataset directly from a colleague or project than scrape it off a web site a little bit at a time.